# Styling custom elements: Font styling

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face, custom-element

I have an element (e.g.  tag). A have set a font-face rule at the root of the document, let's say Noto Sans. Then I have another component which needs another font name,  setting it to Proxima.

**1st scenario.**
Within the component's shadow dom

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Proxima';
    src: url(path/to/font.woff2) format('woff2')
}
 :host{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Proxima';
}
```

Does not work. I even tried adding `!important` but still won't work. Noto Sans overides it.

2nd. I added two font-face, Noto Sans and Proxima,rules at the root document, tried using them both but gets overridden by the former.

Any tips or am I having mistakes in handling my component

Comment: Have you used StackOverflow Search and read previous Question & Answers? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustom-element%5D+font-face

Comment: Yes I have, but ideally I'd like to set it within the component itself and not externally linking it within the document or importing it because the first font loaded overrides the other. Any thoughts about how to do it?